# Makefile target dependencies: How to piece together a variable name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my Makefile, I would like to do something like this

```
OBJ_sound =\
    sound/soundaiff.o\
    sound/sounddummy.o\
    sound/sounddump.o

OBJ_video =\
    video/render.o\
    video/rendercrt.o\
    video/renderntsc.o

lib_%.a: $(OBJ_%)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $+
```

I want, that when target lib_video.a is made, all object files in $(OBJ_video) are packed into lib_video.a and when lib_sound is made, all object files in $(OBJ_sound) are packed into lib_sound.a

But my Makefile snippet above does not work ($+ is always empty). Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to use the [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

lib_%.a: $$(OBJ_$$*)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $+
```

Comment: Your first suggestion cannot work, because target-specific variables are not available in prerequisite lists.